# Returning a variable vs making that variable global

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, global-variables

I have this piece of code here. Let's focus on the `total` variable.

```
def start():
    global total
    total = "$" + str(input("Please enter the amount you want set as your total"))
    if total < 0:
        print("no negative values, try again.")
        start()
    else:
        bets()
```

Would it be better to `return` this variable or turn it into a `global` variable like I already did: `global total`. Both the `return` and `global` keywords feature very similar use cases and so I was wondering whether I should worry about choosing which way I should make that variable accessible to other code

Comment: `return` it.  `global` is the wrong choice 99.9% of the time.

Comment: is there a particular reason?

Comment: One big problem with `global` (among *many* problems) is that the caller has no control over where the output goes; your function might even accidentally overwrite a variable that the caller itself was using for something else!  I'm pretty sure if you google "why is global bad in python" you'll find many many articles explaining the many other reasons.  :)

Comment: @programmingnoob1234590 because global mutable state is a well-known antipattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/337977  For small programs, it's not a big, but as soon as it starts getting bigger, it becomes a big problem. You should get out of the habit of relying on mutable global state